# How to Determine location of OneDrive on Windows 7 and 8 in C++

Tags: visual-c++, onedrive

On Windows 10 I can find the location of OneDrive thru the KnownFolder API using the name OneDrive. However this known folder does not exists on Windows 7 or 8

Is there a reliable registry setting or api that I can use tho get the location of a users OneDrive root folder?

Answer (score 0):

The following registry key has the information

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFWTARE\Microsoft\OneDrive\UserFolder`

Answer (score 0):

Information about OneDrive accounts is stored in

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\OneDrive\Accounts
```

Under this location we could have two items:

- Personal
- Business

Each account has registry string value (UserFolder) which tells us what is the location of particular OneDrive.

[image]

I wrote [PowerShell module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ProductivityTools.PSGetOneDriveDirectory/) which returns required information. The [code](https://github.com/pwujczyk/ProductivityTools.PSGetOneDriveDirectory/blob/master/ProductivityTools.PSGetOneDriveDirectory/ProductivityTools.PSGetOneDriveDirectory.psm1) is simple so you can analyse it.